# How to recover mnemonic and keys?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

Hello I have been mining not much only have 1 monero ... I wonder how I can recover the mnemonic to access and use my monero? I looked in .bitmonero folder but I am totally clueless. I use ubuntu

Comment: Can you still open the wallet with `monero-wallet-cli`?

Comment: I don't know... how do you proceed?

Comment: What I was trying to ask is whether you can still access the wallet with `monero-wallet-cli` or are you 'locked out'?

Comment: Yes I understood, my question was "which command line you use" to access the monero-wallet-cli :)

Comment: How do you normally open `monero-wallet-cli`? Or are you using the GUI? Could you please be a bit more detailed about your setup?